# How many $4-$letter words of the word "history" contain s and t

Tags: combinatorics

I have this question in my statistics textbook. Given the word "history", how many 4-letter words that can be made from this word contain the letters "s" and "t" ?

My approach is this: First, calculate the total number of words and denote that by $\Omega$.

$\Omega  = 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 = 840$.

If we let $s$ and $t$ denote the number of words that *do not* contain "s"and "t" respectively, then the answer will be $\Omega - (s + t) $.

Now, $s = 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 = 360$ . Similarly, $t = 360$, and so the answer is $840 - 2 \times 360 = 120$.

I think I'm overcounting when calculating $s$ and $t$, for example, the word "hiyo" is counted twice in this calculation. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overcouted the words that don't contain s and t. Your answer should be
$$\Omega-(s+t-st)$$
Where $st$ is the set of words that have neither. $st=5\times4\times3\times2=120$
$$\Omega-(s+t-st)=840-2\times360+120=240$$
An other way to see this problem is to evaluate directly the number of words that contain s and t. First choose where you place the s, then where to place the t, finally the remaining two letters.
$$4\times3\times5\times4=240$$

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I'm still a beginner in these questions, can you refer me to a good source that explains inclusion/exclusion principle for a starter?

Answer (score 0):

You are using inclusion/exclusion. After excluding words without s and words without t, you need to include words without either $(5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 = 120)$ for a total of $840-360-360+120=240$.

Alternatively, you can choose $2$ of the $5$ letters h, i, o, r, y in $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways,  then permute them with s and t in $4!=24$ ways for a total of $10\times 24=240$.

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach is to pick $2$ more letters from the remaining $5$ letters in "hi**ory," which can be done in ${5\choose2}=10$ ways, and then arrange the $4$ chosen letters in $4!=24$ ways, for a total of ${5\choose2}4!=10\cdot24=240$ words.

Comment: Ah, this duplicates the second part of Daniel Mathias's answer, which posted while I was composing.